# PHP : how to detect row and column number from HTML table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So, I have a form with a HTML table.

Each box of the table contains a text field. Each of those fields have the same name like this :

```
<input name="quantity[]" type="text" />
```

The HTML table looks like this :

[image: html table with text fields]

Row are numbers. Columns are month.
Users have to put a number (a quantity) in at least one box.

Then, they can submit the form.

My SQL table should be like this :

```
Number - Month - Quantity
222000 - 12 - 50
222000 - 02 - 31
300000 - 01 - 25
221000 - 02 - 28
```

As you see, 1 line in my table = 1 input text.

In PHP, I get the data like this :

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $text_field){
    if(!empty($text_field)) {
        $requete = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO my table VALUES(:number, :month, :quantity)');
        $requete->execute(array(
            ':number' => *???*,
            ':month' => *???*,
            ':quantity' => $text_field
        ));
    }
}
```

My question : how to detect the row number and the column number from my HTML table in PHP and put the result into my SQL table?

Comment: You can do this by using jquery. Use ajax for this purpose first of all fetch all the related data using jquery create an object of it and pass it to php file by using ajax and save it in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume that you have 12 moths and array "numbers" with number value for each row:

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $text_field){
if(!empty($text_field)) {
$number= $numbers[floor($key/12)];
$month=($key%12)+1;


    $requete = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO my table VALUES(:number, :month, :quantity)');
    $requete->execute(array(
        ':number' => $number,
        ':month' => $month,
        ':quantity' => $text_field
    ));
}
```

}

Just dont forget about 0 indexes.

Comment: Thank you, that works ! I would never have thought to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following :

When you populate the table:

```
<input name="quantity[<?= $row ?>][<?= $column ?>]" type="text" />
```

Then in your post handler script:

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $row => $columns){
    foreach ($columns as $column => $text_field) {
        if(!empty($text_field)) {
            $requete = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO my table VALUES(:number, :month, :quantity)');
            $requete->execute(array(
               ':number' => $row,
               ':month' => $column,
               ':quantity' => $text_field
             ));
        }
    }
}
```

In short you make the post fields an associative array rather than a normal one.

Comment: Hi, if I write name="quantity[<?= $row ?>][<?= $column ?>", I have multiple error messages. Where do you declare these 2 variables?

Comment: Those 2 variables indicate the row and column which correspond to that entry.  I've assumed that that was information you (somehow) had access to, if you didn't then  you can declare a row and column counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$n=1;
$num = array(111,222,333,...);

foreach($num as $key=>$n_val)
{
?>
<tr>
 <td>
   <input type="hidden" name="number[<?php echo $key ?>]" 
      value='<?php echo $n_val ?>'/>
   <?php echo $n_val ?>
 </td>
 <td><input name="quantityNov[<?php echo $key ?>]" type="text" /></td>
 <td><input name="quantityDec[<?php echo $key ?>]" type="text" /></td>
 ....
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Then in your submit action portion of php;

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['quantityNov'] as $key => $val)
    {
       $fixed_number = $_POST['number'][$key];
       $month[11] = $val;
       $month[12] = $_POST['quantityDec'][$key];
       $month[1] = $_POST['quantityJan'][$key];
       ...
       $count = 0;
       foreach($month as $month_num=>$n_val)
        if(!empty($n_val)) 
       {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO my table (column(s)) VALUES ('.$fixed_number.','.$month_num.', '.$n_val.')';
            $result = $connection->query($sql);
            $count += $connection->affected_rows;
        }
    }
echo 'Number of rows inserted: '.$count;
?>
```

This is how I like to write my code, but you can write it in your preferred style, but I think this will get you going.

Comment: Your example is open to SQL injection

Comment: +way more spaghetti and much worse performance than in original code.

Comment: @DarkBee, how so? all three are numeric with no quotations. So how would anyone be able to inject string?

Comment: only thing I see is you using direct user input inside a query

Comment: How or why would u escape numeric values?

Comment: PHP uses type juggling, what you are calling "numeric" doesn't add up. What if I post something like `$fixed_number="', 1, 1); DELETE FROM mytable;#"`. To prevent SQL injection you should need to use prepared statements and placeholders for the variable and let the DB driver handle it

Comment: good point. i don't allow deletion for any level user who connects through php, by db access permission, i just mark records for deletion and not show in next queries. so i never thought of this, but valid point! Thanx!